# laravel insert data in multiple rows and in one loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an issue in laravel with inserting data in multiple rows. I managed to insert the names in the ingredient table but I would like to add 2 other inputs (unit and quantity).

Can I do this without creating two more loops ?

Controller:

```
public function store() {

   $meal = new Meal;
   $meal->name = Input::get('name');
   $ingredient_names = Input::get('ingredient_names');
   $meal_ingredients = array();
   foreach($ingredient_names as $ingredient_name)
   {
        $meal_ingredients[] = new Ingredient(array(
            'name'=>$ingredient_name
        ));
   }

    //save  into the DB
    $meal->save();
    $meal->ingredients()->saveMany($meal_ingredients);
}
```

create.blade.html:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'meals.store')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
                {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>
            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredient_names[]">
                <a class="add_field_button">Ajouter</a>
            </div>


            {{ Form::submit('Valider', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
       {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

meal.js (just to show you that I am using dynamic fields)

```
// dynamic fields
var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initial text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredient_names[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Supprimer</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

Comment: Quantity and unit belongs to the ingredient right? Why you need to do other loops if the field count is the same, so you can simply populate the unit and quantity in the same loop?!

Comment: yes quantity and unit belong to the ingredient. well I would have to do two other foreach loops like the foreach for the ingredient_names ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input fields can be arrays. I would recommend that for each ingredient, you have inputs like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('ingredient[0][name]', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('unit', 'Unit') }}
            {{ Form::text('ingredient[0][unit]', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity') }}
            {{ Form::text('ingredient[0][quantity]', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, whenever you add a row, increment the ingredient index so that the next row's inputs are like so: `ingredient[1][name]`, etc. Then your store method would look like this:

```
public function store() {
   $meal = new Meal;
   $meal->name = Input::get('name');

   $ingredients = Input::get('ingredient');
   $meal_ingredients = array();

   foreach($ingredients as $ingredient)
   {
        $meal_ingredients[] = new Ingredient(array(
            'name' => $ingredient['name'],
            'unit' => $ingredient['unit'],
            'quantity' => $ingredient['quantity'],
        ));
   }

    //save  into the DB
    $meal->save();
    $meal->ingredients()->saveMany($meal_ingredients);
}
```

I am not too familiar with the `Form` class, so the syntax to get your inputs to be arrays might be slightly different, but essentially, you want to end up with this:

```
<input type='text' name='ingredient[0][name]' />
```